# Recent Activity Pages CSS issue - Also blocking clicks on range selection

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, recent-activity, design

Apologies if it's a dupe, couldn't find it.
Starting a few days ago I'm seeing this behavior on the iPhone:

[image: Full View] [image: Zoomed View]
This is the same screen normal and zoomed in for a closer view.

Since I use this to check recent comments and such to follow up on...making the `today` hard to click really limits the usability of the page (there's no `?time=today` I'm aware of, so a plain refresh doesn't work here).

Can we get a CSS adjustment so this overlap doesn't happen?  Before, though I may be crazy, it seems like the comments were wider as well, so maybe it's related to that same batch of CSS changes.

---

**Update:**  It's also causing click issues, here are screenshots from chrome 6.0.472.63 (stable) and Firefox 3.6.10 respectively:
[image: Chrome]

---

[image: Firefox]

The area that the `<h2>` overlaps the day buttons isn't clickable, since the clicks go to the `<h2>` element.

Comment: I'm not sure if SO supports Safari on an iPhone

Comment: The elements have `font-size: 140%` applied to them, so it might have something to do with the default font-size used by Mobile Safari

Comment: Same problem here with Chrome 7.0.517.24, Safari 5.0.2 and Firefox 4.0b6.

Comment: I can repro. We're fixing this.

Comment: @Jin - Can you post an answer so I can accept/close it out? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is on production now.

Comment: Thanks! (this message brought to you by the 15 character comment limit)